# Wizard progress bar funciona apenas após atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, javascript-eventos

Ao integrar o wizard twitter bootstrap a minha aplicação, percebi que o progress bar funciona apenas quando atualizo a pagina.
Vi em alguns lugares que isso pode ser causado pelo turbolinks porém não encontrei nenhuma solução para o problema.
Utilizo o rails 5.1 e o turbolinks 5 em minha aplicação.